# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc, mssql-jdbc

While I try to execute the following code, I am getting this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1

Please be patient as I am new to java

Note : My_info file has the details of database ,username and password

```
public class acesss {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Connection connect = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            Properties identity = new Properties();


            String rootPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
            String info_file = rootPath + "my_info";


            try {
              identity.load(new FileInputStream(info_file));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }



            String user = identity.getProperty("user");
            String password = identity.getProperty("password");
            String database = identity.getProperty("database");

            try {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");


                connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db.ca:3310", user, password);


                statement = connect.createStatement();


                statement.executeQuery("use "+ database+";");


                resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from product;");

                while (resultSet.next()) {

                    System.out.print(resultSet.getString("LastName")+" | ");
                    System.out.print(resultSet.getString("product_name")+" | ");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } finally {


                try {
                    if (resultSet != null) {
                        resultSet.close();
                    }

                    if (statement != null) {
                        statement.close();
                    }

                    if (connect != null) {
                        connect.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am guessing that `database` is null - debug and check

Comment: Also usually you state your DB as per `String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/yourdatabase";`

Comment: You're ignoring exceptions (empty catch block) when you load your properties file. Don't do that, because you do f see the errors now. Probably your properties file isn't found

Comment: The database is not null.I checked it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error. There was some problem with the my_info file.I had to swap the order of the username,  database and password and it worked.